# Alternative SignalR Redis implementation within Load Balancer Environment

Tags: c#, iis, signalr, load-balancing, asp.net-core-webapi

We have completed a hybrid mobile application that makes use of SignalR (.Net Core) on the backend.

The issue we have now discovered is that, SignalR does not play nicely with load balancers and although there is Azure and Redis, to get this approved will be a nightmare.

Does anyone know of any alternative solution we can deploy without having to go to the architecture forum for approval of Redis.

Ideally, within C# WebApi and deploy to IIS.

**NOTE! We cannot make use of Redis or Azure in our case.**

Quick update: going to test this solution tomorrow. If we are successful, I will post an official answer.

https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/aspnetcore-master/package/nuget/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.SqlServer

Comment: The [docs for scaling out SignalR on net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-2.2) say explicitly _"The options for solving [your] problem are the Azure SignalR Service and Redis backplane."_

Comment: This [github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5277) discussed about "SQL Server backplane for ASP.NET Core SignalR", as anurse mentioned `SQL isn't really designed for this purpose (real-time pub/sub)`, and there are no current plans to build a SQL Server backplane with ASP.NET Core SignalR.